# Deserealization not working properly

Tags: c#, json

I've create a class for deserialize [this JSON](http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/19/players)

```
public class Self
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Links
{
    public Self _self { get; set; }
    public Team team { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
    public int jerseyNumber { get; set; }
    public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string nationality { get; set; }
    public string contractUntil { get; set; }
    public string marketValue { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Links _links { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Player> players { get; set; }
}

public struct Player_Struct
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
    public string position;
    public int jerseyNumber;
    public string dateOfBirth;
    public string nationality;
    public string contractUntil;
    public string marketValue;
}
```

So I made a function to create an HttpRequest and the relative object:

```
 string requestUrl = teams.link_teams;
 string responseText = parser.Request(requestUrl);
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Players.RootObject>(responseText);
```

Now the problem's that the compiler return this exception:

> Unhandled exception 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Ulteriori informazioni: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'SF_DebugProject.API.Players+Links' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '_links', line 1, position 11.

So with the fix hint I've tried to repair the error change the object into:

```
List<Players.RootObject> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Players.RootObject>>(responseText);
```

but in this way I can't see any attribute of the rootobject when I do the foreach. What I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the json? The message says that the input shape doesn't match the target types. Deserialization can't change the shape of the data. If your input contains an array of players with no other data, you can't force it to become a `RootObject`

Comment: The json is here: http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/19/players
anyway, with this object I can see the parameter of the RootObject: 
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Players.RootObject>(responseText); 
but for a strange reason an exception is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to deserialize a JSON string in a RootObject that contains a list of players.

The classes should look like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public _Links _links { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public Player[] players { get; set; }
}

public class _Links
{
    public _Self _self { get; set; }
    public Team team { get; set; }
}

public class _Self
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
    public int jerseyNumber { get; set; }
    public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string nationality { get; set; }
    public string contractUntil { get; set; }
    public string marketValue { get; set; }
}
```

So what you should do is something like the following :

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
foreach(var player in obj.players) 
{
     // some stuff
}
```

Comment: he is exactly doing this

Comment: In fact I already do this. My problem is that I can not see the parameters of each players. The parameters are those contained in the Player class. Referring to the first obj instead I can see the parameters (variable), the point is that during the execution of the function I get an exception.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to show the C# classes to be used.

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'SF_DebugProject.API.Players+_Links' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: I tried it on my machine and it works. Are you sure the JSON string you pass to JsonConvert is ok ?

Comment: Okay, sorry for the mistake the link of my struct passed in the function was incorrect. Thank you :)